# Jenkins (Hudson) plugin to translate revision number to build number

Tags: build, hudson, jenkins, revision, hudson-plugins

I'm looking to a Jenkins (fka Hudson) plugin to visualize which revision number is connected to each build number (SCM is SVN, build done by maven).

Does anyone know of such a plugin?

Update1:
Yes, I know of svn tags, we use them, we can go to svn to understand this information - but it's a cumbersome way to understand which build includes my fix.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [description setter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin) plugin with regex `Updated to revision (.*)` and description  `r\1`

Comment: I would use that - but the problem is that we don't keep the builds on the hudson machine for a long time, so this information is lost when the build is automatically deleted. I'm looking for something that'll keep even after the build itself is deleted.